# Adding commas to string in python as per requirement

Tags: python-3.x

```
number = ("98956784528562359856745395125874589652368745269874")
```

I want to add commas to this string as per requirement not as per currency or other denominations, for example in this string I want to add ,(comma) after 10 places i.e number[9] and so on. I tried it with join method but it didn't work

The output should be like this:

```
9895678452,8562359856,7453951258,7458965236,8745269874,
```

Comment: The output should be like this:9895678452,8562359856,7453951258,7458965236,8745269874,

Comment: Edit your question and include the failed attempt at this.

Comment: Actually I used your link but voted to close, that you cannot do :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression

```
import re
print re.sub("(.{10})", "\\1,", number, 0, re.DOTALL)
```